# Share lists of venues between friends

Tags: web-apps, wishlist

My group of friends would like to try multiple venues (bar, restaurants, cafes) in a rather systematic way (for instance, following some "*list of the 10 places with the best beer in X*"). Intuitively, the requirements should be:

- work as a web-app, possibly as a plugin of an existing app (Facebook, TripAdvisor, etc)
- the group members are identified, and new members can be invited (in a similar way to Facebook groups).
- anybody in the group can add a new venue, with some information.
- anybody in the group can add a review of a venue.
- at any time, it is possible to know which venues one has attended and one has not.

My first idea was to use a Facebook group, and post each venue as a new post, but it's sub-optimal, since the last requirement is not fulfilled, and it would require to create a new group for each list (e.g., one group for bar, one group for restaurant, etc).

Are there any web-app addressing these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you need to create a private group on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/) - which will allow members to add places, photos, discussions, etc. and they will be able to see which places they have been to on their own "local" tab.

- Free
- Web
- Mobile App available
- Cross platform
- Can invite new members
- Can have events - like lets all meet up at this venue on this date
- More selective views than FB.